Constructing a meromorphic function on a Riemann surface
Suppose that $X$ is a compact and connected Riemann surface nad that $p \in X$.
I want to construct a meromorphic function $f$ on $X$ such that ${\rm old}_p(f) = 1434$.
Note that there are no restrictions on the poles or zeroes at other points.
I believe that the sum of the orders of the zeroes and the poles needs to come to zero so we should put poles that total order 1434 somewhere else and we can use Riemann Roch somehow to show that such a function exists.
